# Число имен существительных

Tags: морфология

Как вы считаете, почему существительные  "рубашка", "плащ", "пиджак" имеют форму единственного числа, а "брюки", "трусы", "штаны" - форму множественного числа?

Answer (score 2):

*Человек затем и раздвоен снизу, а не сверху, чтобы не ходить вверх ногами.* ©Козьма Прутков

Предметы одежды, носимые на ногах, традиционно рассматривались как парные, состоящие из двух половин (штанин).

> Поводом к вопросу послужила статья в одном журнальчике. ТАм упоминалось о том, что изначально одежда типа трусов и штанов представляла собой две отдельные половинки, которые присоединялись к поясу. (Как чулки). И поэтому они употребляются только в форме множественного числа. Объяснение логичное, но вот насколько верное? ТАк ли было? Больше нигде информацию не нашла.

([[@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f))

Короче, посмотрел я все доступные источники - нет и никогда. Ни славяне, ни древние германцы никогда не носили брюк, состоящих из двух *разделённых* половин. Про другие народы смотреть бесполезно, европейцы - а через них и славяне - узнали о брюках от германцев (это факт известный). Скорее всего аторы нашей сенсации неверно интерпретировали какую-то фразу *о способе изготовления* первых брюк. Они кроились из двух половин, которые потом сшивались по "седловой линии" (т.е. промежности). Впрочем, и сейчас почти так же, с небольшими дополнениями.  И если речь об этом, то я согласен. Но брюки или штаны никогда не пристёгивались к поясу *поотдельности*.

Comment: Руки тоже две

Comment: А что вы носите *на руках* кроме перчаток и нарукавников?
рубашки, плащи и пиджаки - одежда *нательная*. В соответвующем смысле.

А, манжеты еще. Ну так они тоже парные.

Comment: Кстати. Руки - они не совсем парные. Они - десница и шуя. Вы можете представить себе такое "непарное" использование ног?

Comment: "У кого толчковая - левая, а у меня толчковая - правая"

Comment: Поводом к вопросу послужила статья в одном журнальчике. ТАм упоминалось о том, что изначально одежда типа трусов и штанов представляла собой две отдельные половинки, которые присоединялись к поясу. (Как чулки). И поэтому они употребляются только в форме множественного числа. Объяснение логичное, но вот насколько верное? ТАк ли было? Больше нигде информацию не нашла.

Comment: Даже если такое и было (что вряд ли), эта древняя история никак не объясняет современную норму. Как минимум восприятие брюк и штанов как предметов, состоящих из двух половин, должно сохраниться до современности.

Comment: "Изначально каждая штанина была отдельным предметом, поэтому во многих языках название этого вида одежды является существительным множественного или двойственного числа."  
Это из вики. Не заню, как трактовать - и верить ли. Получается,  что трусы(!) совсем даже не прикрывали библейское место и ягодицы, а начинались от бедер? Никогда о таком не слышал.

Comment: Короче, посмотрел я все доступные источники - нет и никогда. Ни славяне, ни древние германцы никогда не носили брюк, сочтоящих из двух разделённыз половин. другие народы смотреть бесполезно, европейцы - а через них и славяни узнали о брюках от германцев (это факт известный). Скорее всего аторы этой сенсации неверно интерпретировали какую-то фразу о способе изготовления первых брюк. Они кроились из двух половин, которые потом сшивались по "седловой линии" (т.е. промежности). Если речь об этом, то я согласен. Но никак не пристёгивались к поясу.